# Picture Boxes in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am having a problem with adding some `picture boxes`. I have a `form` (and it's class) and a separate class. What i want to do is to put some `picture boxes` from my second class in the `form`, but it seems I just can't figure out how. Oh, and I don't want to send the picture box from the second class to the main one, and add it there, but just add it directly. If I try something like:

```
Form1.ActiveForm.Controls.Add(x);
```

(where x is my picture box) from the second class I get `'Cross-thread operation not valid'` exception.

Thanks for any advices!

Comment: 1. Read your error message. 2. Attempt to understand your error message. It is a common error and this question has been asked before.

Comment: Did you try google.com?

Comment: Your error message refers to multiple threads, but your problem description does not.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run show your picture on a non-UI thread? Usually this is how you get a cross-thread operation not valid exception.

You may simple need to do something like the following in your class.

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
   this.Invoke(() => ActiveForm.Controls.Add(x));
}
else
{
   ActiveForm.Controls.Add(x);
}
```

This will ensure you are using the UI thread to execute your code.